# Why I get strange characters when looping an array on C++

Tags: c++

This is my main function:

```
string a[18] = {
    "1", " " ,"2", " ", "3", "\n",
    "4", " " ,"5", " ", "6", "\n",
    "7", " " ,"8", " ", "9", "\n" };

for (int x = 0; x <= 18; x++)
{ 
    cout << a[x];
}
```

and the output is something like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
\�V�W(SV��8\�V������
```

Am I looping my array incorrectly?

PS: I am on mac

Comment: Please do some [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of that loop. What is the top index for an array of `18` elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an array of `18` elements, the only valid indexes are `0 .. 17`.

You need to change the loop to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 18; ++xx)
{ 
    cout << a[x];
}
```

otherwise, you invoke undefined behaviour on the the last iteration of the loop, if you try to index `a[18]`.

Answer (score 2):

It is printing `a[18]`, which is out of boundary of array `a`.

You need to use `x < 18`, not `x <= 18`.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is going out of bounds of the array.

A safer way to iterate the array is to use a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead:

```
string a[18] = {
    "1", " " ,"2", " ", "3", "\n",
    "4", " " ,"5", " ", "6", "\n",
    "7", " " ,"8", " ", "9", "\n"
};

for (auto &s : a)
{
    cout << s;
}
```